# Default to trunk version for Mercurial merges?

Tags: mercurial, merge

When we merge changes from our Mercurial feature release repositories into our trunk repository, we always have conflicts with our Maven POM files(pom.xml) and our Mercurial .hgtags file.

We always want to keep the trunk version - we never want the feature release repo version.  Is there any way to tell Mercurial to always use the trunk version of these files when there are merge conflicts?

---

**Update**: Per the selected answer, this works:

```
[merge-patterns]
.hgtags = internal:local
pom.xml = internal:local
**\pom.xml = internal:local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `pom.xml` file set the merge tool to `internal:local` (or `internal:remote` if you're not updated to what you're calling *trunk)*.  Explained [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration).
Try this:

```
[merge-patterns]
pom.xml = internal:local
```

Comment: Really?  It seemed pretty clear, but I copy/pasted it into the answer and changed the filename for you.

Comment: Regarding `pom.xml = internal:local`, if you want this to apply to any pom file in any subdir would you need something like `**\pom.xml = internal:local`?

Comment: Yes, and Yes, but it's probably faster to just try this out in a test repo than to ask at this point.