# Mercurial - Exceptions to internal:local merge-patterns?

Tags: mercurial, merge

To ensure we use the trunk version of some files when merging [we use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070544/default-to-trunk-version-for-mercurial-merges) `internal:local`:

```
[merge-patterns]
.hgtags = internal:local
pom.xml = internal:local
```

It seems in some cases, the merge does NOT use the local file, it does actually merge the changes from the remote repository.  Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 4):

The Mercurial "premerge" internal merge is actually successfully resolving merge conflicts for certain files before even launching a merge tool.

> If the chosen merge tools premerge is
>   True then an internal merge is
>   attempted, and if it seems successful
>   then the result it will silently be
>   used without running the actual merge
>   tool

Check out [this article](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) on merge tool configuration for more info. Turning off premerge for a particular type of file (or directory) can be done using these modifications to your Mercurial.ini file:

```
[merge-tools]
<name>.premerge = False
<name>.args = --auto $base $other $other -o $output
<name>.executable = kdiff3

[merge-patterns]
**.xml = <name>
.hgtags = <name>
```

Note that kdiff3 should come with TortoiseHg by default, and `<name>` can be anything you want; call it, 'localFilesOnly' or something like that.

Comment: Thanks - do you have an example config?  Not entirely sure how set up this config..

Comment: @Marcus - updated to include an example. You will have to tweak the `[merge-patterns]` section for your own files.

Comment: This makes sense for skipping the premerge, but how do you skip the premerge AND tell mercurial if they are diffs to use the local file?

Comment: the `executable` parameter is defining that kdiff3 should be used for the merge, and the `args` parameter is specifying an argument pattern that will force kdiff23 to always take either the local or other file. In the example above, it's set to always take the 'other' file (ie: the changes being merged back in), but you can tweak this to always discard changes during the merge. I'd have to experiment a bit, but you can try using `--auto $base $base $base -o $output`