# Preventing version merges between VCS branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, continuous-integration, dvcs, continuous-deployment

there's an "issue" (actually a nuisance, but a major one) with our development process.

We've setup a good continuous integration-deployment-delivery pipeline; basically, our process is like that:

New development happens on the **default** branch (we use Mercurial, but git would have the same issue); usually we develop just one small improvement there;

Once the improvement is ready and tested (something that usually happens twice or three times a week, our cycle is pretty short), it's merged into the **release** branch (which actually stands for *release candidate*), it's tested again in a production-like environment and if it passes all our testing it's pushed to the production environment.

If we need to make a bugfix, we do it on the release branch, we test it and then push it to the production env.

An artifact (usually an RPM package) is built from each branch; when there's a release in production, the very artifact from the release branch is promoted to our public repository. There's no branch for the production environment, because we usually don't need it (there's a very short timespan when something it's on the release branch but it's not in production; code doesn't linger there unattended).

In this context, there's a small issue for us.

In order to distinguish packages, we usually set version to 1 for packages on the release branch, and 2 to packages on the default branch. Our CI system then adds its build number, so we've got packages like *oursoftware-1.0-build37* for release and *oursoftware-1.0-build902* for default. Such version is written either in our .spec file or in our pom.xml files (or other files for different softwares, like .gemspec or simila)

Whenever we want to put something in release candidate, we merge the default branch to the release branch.

What happens there? **the version gets merged as well**. So after each merge we need to get back at the file containing the version and put the old version in them. We should need to do it just once (Mercurial does not try to re-merge things that were already merged) but whenever we need to do a merge from release from default (e.g. in order to merge a fix done on release to the dev branch) the problem rises again.

I'd like some advice on how to prevent this problem completely; **how do I set versions outside of my branches?** I sometimes actually need to change them (e.g. I want to change from 1 to 2 on release and from 2 to 3 on default) and I wouldn't like to hardcode them in our CI system, I'd like some system which is "outside" the scope of branches and it's kind of "global" for a repository. Or I would need something like "ignore modification for some files".

In many situations I actually need versions in my files as well; for example I cannot omit version info from a Maven pom.xml file or from a .gemspec, otherwise it won't work when developing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see <strike>3</strike> <strike>4</strike> *a lot of* possible solution, more or less "native" (random order without priorities and own personal preferences)

- Instead of "Monolitic $DEVEL branch" you can use "Branch Per task": in this case file with (hardcoded) version-info will not appear as mergeable file (TBT!)
- Branch-specific version change can be moved from (permanent) changeset of branch into patch of MQ (as results - versions /and files/ are identical across branches, permanent default changes have to appear as result of applying patch)
- Files with version-info doesn't contain hardcoded versions, they are more "templates", than "data", and real data appear as result of some preprocessing inside build process (you know transformation-rules and can code it)
- You can change nothing in developent|deploy process and **if** version-info files are **unique inside repository**, you can use trick, similar to [merging hgtags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783478/960558) (special mergetool for only some files in repo - in your case in must be `internal:local` special mergetool)
- Maybe using just merge-patterns will be OK for you, check [Mercurial - Exceptions to internal:local merge-patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656112/mercurial-exceptions-to-internallocal-merge-patterns) and [Default to trunk version for Mercurial merges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070544/default-to-trunk-version-for-mercurial-merges) for details and some additional notes+discoveries